# Rare bug: comments expanding over bottom bar

Tags: bug, comment, design

The situation is exemplified below.

Before expanding comments:

[image]

---

After expanding the comments:

[image]

I couldn't reproduce it after several reloads. However, I think the situation above occurred just after I reopened the thread, so it might have to do with that.

Can someone look into this?

Comment: Can you also provide a link?

Comment: It's [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/640843/43351). I suspect it has to do with the answer box being unavailable for closed questions.